# remove space between paper title and abstract in AAAI

Tags: spacing, formatting, titles

I want to remove the space between the title and abstract (marked as red box in the following pic) to save some space for my paper, I've seen some similar questions and people suggest using /vspace, I wonder is there a cleaner solution to this?[image]

and here is what I've got so far

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{aaai}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\frenchspacing
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}
\pdfinfo{
/Title (Insert Your Title Here)
/Author (Put All Your Authors Here, Separated by Commas)}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}  
 \begin{document}
\title{Formatting Instructions for Authors Using \LaTeX{}}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\begin{quote}
AAAI creates ...
\end{quote}
\end{abstract}

\noindent Congratulations...
\vfill
\break

\section{Copyright}
All papers submitted for publicatio

\end{document}
```

Comment: Be careful about doing this - violating the style guidelines can result in your paper being rejected. In particular AAAI author instructions state: _Modifications to the style sheet (or your document) in an effort to avoid extra page charges are NOT allowed._ They explicitly forbid the use of `\vspace`.

Comment: thanks @NathanS. I've seen them, but those are for the final version of the papers, for initial submission seems to be Okay, even though it hasn't been confirmed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking into the [aaai.sty](http://www.aaai.org/Publications/Author/author.php) file will learn that the area is controlled by `titlebox` whose default value is 2.25in. Therefore, use a less value in the preamble should remove the space, displayed below

```
\setlength\titlebox{1in}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{aaai}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\frenchspacing
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}
\pdfinfo{
/Title (Insert Your Title Here)
/Author (Put All Your Authors Here, Separated by Commas)}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}  
\setlength\titlebox{1in}           % default=2.25in
 \begin{document}
\title{Formatting Instructions for Authors Using \LaTeX{}}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\begin{quote}
AAAI creates ...
\end{quote}
\end{abstract}

\noindent Congratulations...
\vfill
\break

\section{Copyright}
All papers submitted for publicatio

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that for some reason, following AAAI's suggestion and putting the `\setlength\titlebox` line right after the `\documentclass` line caused me errors, but putting it where you have it worked fine.

Comment: @NathanS. Not `right after` the \documentclass, but after the loading of packages.

Comment: Their instructions say "If the title and author information does not fit in the area allocated, place `\setlength\titlebox{height}` after the `\documentclass` line where _height_ is something like `2.5in`." Anyway, I tried a few things that didn't work, but followed your placement to get it working. (+1)